# Perl, how to parse XML file, xpath

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-parsing

I want to parse an XML file using **Perl**. I was able to do it using the **XML::Simple** module, but now I want to start using the **XML::XPath** module instead because it uses **XPath** expressions. From my limited knowledge I think XPaths will make future parsing easier, right?
Here's the Perl code I have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::XPath;

my $file = "data.xml";
my $path = XML::XPath->new(filename => $file);

my $name = $path->find('/category/event/@name');
print $name."\n";
```

My question is how do I separate each name attribute (category/event/@**name**) so that I can perform tests on each value I parse. At the moment I'm just getting a big string full of the parsed data, whereas I want several small strings that I can test. How can I do this? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This review](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/XML-XPath#3500) points out that [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::XPath) hasn't been updated since 2003, and recommends [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) instead

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('data.xml');
for my $node ($dom->findnodes('/category/event/@name')) {
    say $node->toString;
}
```

See [`XML::LibXML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::Parser) and [`XML::LibXML::Node`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::Node).

Comment: are you recommending `XML::LibXML` because you know it better, or because you think it has a genuine advantage over `XML::XPath`? As far as I know the latter works fine. It is also pure Perl, which makes it slower than LibXML but usable without the help of an external library.

Comment: That's a hyper-link up there. Do follow it.

Comment: @daxim Thanks for the reply. I tried that it it worked, but not 100% the way I wanted. My output is name="attribute_value", but I want just attribute_value. Is there a way to just output the attribute_value without the name=""?

Comment: After a bit more research I found that changing the line ´$node->toString´ to ´$node->to_literal´ gives me output of just the attribute_value with no name="". This is what I wanted. If this is a bad way to do things, please tell me, otherwise my question is answered. Thanks again for the help :-)

Answer (score 7):

The `find` method returns an [`XML::XPath::NodeSet`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::XPath::NodeSet) object which is a *collection* of all the nodes found. I can't imagine what you can have done to see one long string with all of the attribute values.

Having retrieved the set of nodes, you work on its contents with methods like `size`, `get_node` and `get_nodelist` (see the docs I've linked above). `get_nodelist` will return a Perl list of, in this case, [`XML::XPath::Node::Attribute`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::XPath::Node::Attribute) objects which also have their own methods. This program should get you started

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::XPath;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(ioref => \*DATA);

my $names = $xp->find('/category/event/@name');

for my $node ($names->get_nodelist) {
  say $node->getNodeValue;
}


__DATA__
  <category name="a">
    <event name="cat1" />  
    <event name="cat2" />  
    <event name="cat3" />  
    <event name="cat4" />  
    <event name="cat5" />  
  </category>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
cat1
cat2
cat3
cat4
cat5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After reading the link posted by daxim I've decided to use XML::LibXML instead. It seems to be the best one out there, so as a beginner I think it would be better for me to learn a module that is better documented. I appreciate the introduction info you wrote, it helped me understand things a bit better :-)

Comment: using `XML::XPath`, can we use `^` or `*` inside path?.
EX  : `my $names = $xp->find('/category/eve*');`.Inside `category`, search for tag starting with `eve`